# Recursive descent parser for arithmetic expressions in smlnj

Tags: sml, smlnj, recursive-descent

I have to write a recursive descent parser in SML, similar to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227947/8876860). I have to write it for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division operations only.

The parser should be able to handle precedence of operators, and parenthesis.

Here's what I have written till now -

```
    exception invalid

fun parseExpression ([], x2) = (x2, [])
|   parseExpression (h2::t2, x2) =
    let
        fun parseTerm ([], x1) = (x1, [])
        |   parseTerm (h1::t1, x1) =
            let
                fun parseFactor ([], x) = (x, [])
                |   parseFactor (h::t, x) =
                    if(h = "~") then 
                        let val (a, b) = parseFactor(t, x) in (~1 * a, b) end
                    else if(h = "(") then parseExpression (t, x)
                    else if(h = ")") then (x, t)
                    else
                        let
                            val v1 = Int.fromString(h)
                        in
                            case v1 of
                            SOME v => (v, t)
                            | NONE => raise invalid
                        end
                val (y1, yl1::ys1) = parseFactor (h1::t1, x1)
            in
                if(yl1 = "/") then
                    let val (elm1, exp1) = parseFactor (ys1, x1) in parseTerm(exp1, y1 div elm1) end
                else if(yl1 = "*") then
                    let val (elm1, exp1) = parseFactor (ys1, x1) in parseTerm(exp1, y1 * elm1) end
                else (y1, yl1::ys1)
            end
        val (y, yl::ys) = parseTerm (h2::t2, x2)
    in
        if(yl = "+") then
            let val (elm, exp) = parseTerm (ys, x2) in parseExpression(exp, y + elm) end
        else if(yl = "-") then
            let val (elm, exp) = parseTerm (ys, x2) in parseExpression(exp, y - elm) end
        else (y, yl::ys)
    end

fun parse L =
    let
        val (x, L1) = parseExpression (L, 0)
    in
        if(L1 = []) then x
        else raise invalid
    end
fun takeinput () =
    let
        val inp = TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn
        val exp = case inp of
                    SOME s => s
                  | NONE => raise invalid
        val tkns = String.tokens Char.isSpace exp
    in
        parse tkns
    end
end
```

The input to the `parse` function is a list of string tokens of the expression.

for normal three operand expressions like - 
45 + 52 * 6 
the function is running fine but for larger expressions including parenthesis, it raises **bind** and **invalid** exceptions.

Any help with the code is appreciated.

I think that I've not implemented the `for` constructs like this -

```
for (;;) {
                if      (eat('+')) x += parseTerm(); // addition
                else if (eat('-')) x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
                else return x;
            }
```

the `eat` function and evaluation of `parenthesis` properly.
I got a bit confused about what to do when I see a closing parenthesis.

Comment: The code also fails on smaller inputs like `1` and `~1` and `1 + 1` and `1 * 1`. Start with getting the simplest cases correct and then work your way upwards.

Comment: (Adding the SML tag since there's nothing New Jersey-specific about this.)

Comment: Initially, I started with two operands only, then I moved to larger expressions, but somehow the program is now not evaluating anything.

Comment: For `~1`  you should write `~ 1`, because it will separate `~` and `1` tokens using space.